# Binding to the click event of a submit button, will our JS run before the form submits?

Tags: javascript, submit

We are currently binding to the click event of a submit button (there are reasons why we are not binding to the submit event for the form). Is it guaranteed that our JS will run before the form submits (as we are entering values into hidden fields that we want to submit) or do we need to prevent the form from submitting and then call the submit again?

```
$(function() {
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
        // Do some stuff here - needs to finish before the form submits

        return true;
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As long as your "do some stuff here" doesn't include any asynchronous code you'll be fine. What are your reasons for not binding to the submit event? (You know you can bind multiple submit handlers to the same form if you need to?)

Comment: I think the submit action is the last step, but you can always try both ways and see which one works

Answer (score 0):

In my expierience the code in the click event will always run first.

I just ran a simple test on latest chrome with a loop that loops 10,000 times.  The form did not submit until after the loop was finished (~5 seconds).

If you try to run some ajax call, or setTimeout in the click function though, the form will most likely submit before your callback/ajax is finished.

Answer (score 0):

It will work before the submit event is sent, but you are only listening for the `click` event. If the user hits `enter`, the form will be submitted without running your code. I think you should stick to the `submit` event. The callback function will receive as argument the `event` (and you can do things like `e.preventDefault();` or `e.stopPropagation();`

```
$("form").on("submit",function(event){});
```